# How to make sticky header change link colour on scroll?

Tags: javascript

Looking for a way to change link colour in JavaScript within a specific ID on scroll.

That's my CSS.

```
  #header_nav {
  transition: 0.4s;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 130px;
  }
  
  #main-logo {
    transition: 0.4s;
    height: 52px;
    width: 169.92px;
  }
  
  #main-nav a{
   color: #f3f5f6;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
```

And here is the JavaScript

```
function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
   
    document.getElementById("header_nav").style.height = "70px";
    document.getElementById("main-logo").style.width = "118.944px";
    document.getElementById("main-logo").style.height = "36.4px";
    document.getElementById("main-logo").style.filter = "invert(0)";
    document.getElementById("header_nav").style.backgroundColor = "#F1F1F3";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "25px";
    document.getElementById("main-nav a").style.color = "#223732";
   
    
  } else {
    document.getElementById("header_nav").style.height = "130px";
    document.getElementById("header_nav").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    document.getElementById("main-logo").style.filter = "invert(1)";
    document.getElementById("main-logo").style.width = "169.92px";
    document.getElementById("main-logo").style.height = "52px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "35px";
    document.querySelectorAll(".main-nav a").style.color = "#f3f5f6";
  }
}
```

You can see where I have the code that doesn't work:

```
document.getElementById("main-nav a").style.color = "#223732";
```

Is there a way I can select just the link in javascript D from that id as I have it in CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first select the main-nav by id and then it's children by tag name, something like:

```
var mainNav = document.getElementById("main-nav");
mainNav.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.color = "#223732";
```

Not that getElementsByTagName() returns an array with all elements of that tag.

Comment: Tried it, and it doesn't change.

Comment: Need to see your html code to be of any more help